# HTML & VBA Visual Basic automatic input website

Tags: html, vba, excel

My company has a "link" I can go to... http://blablabla... where there is a box where I can enter an 8 digit number (next to the box it says lot name) and a button where I can click view report. That's it. That's all that's on the page. (input box and a view report button)

I have a list of numbers in excel in cell range B3:B7 for example (10378851, 10378857, 10488213, etc. )

I want to open excel and run a code that automatically goes to the website, automatically inputs the first number, automatically "clicks" the view report button.

Then there will be an "export data button" - I want to automatically click which will have a drop down (csv, txt, excel, etc.) I want to automatically select "excel"

I found a site that explains how to do something similar but I am stuck.

```
Sub GetTable()

Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieTable As Object
Dim clip As DataObject

'create a new instance of ie
Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

'you don’t need this, but it’s good for debugging
ieApp.Visible = True

'assume we’re not logged in and just go directly to the login page
ieApp.Navigate "http://severe-frost-552.heroku.com/login"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

'fill in the login form – View Source from your browser to get the control names
With ieDoc.forms(0)
.login.Value = "dailydose"
.Password.Value = "password"
.submit
End With
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'now that we’re in, the rest of this code isn't relevant because it copied a table of data...
```

Here is the website...

http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2011/03/08/get-data-from-website-that-requires-a-login/

As you can see, there source code says:

```html
<form action="/session" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:in...
<input id="login" name="login" type="text" /></p>
```

I think that is where they are getting this part of their code:

```
With ieDoc.forms(0)
.login.Value = "dailydose"
```

Looking at my websites source code, it looks like I have:

```html
<DIV id=ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03><INPUT id=ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue class=null style= size=30 name=ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl03$txtValue> </DIV>
<INPUT id=ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue class=null style= size=30 name=ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl03$txtValue>
```

I think this is the right area of the code because when I type "hello" into the input box it shows up there like this:

```html
<INPUT id=ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue class=null style= size=30 value=Hello name=ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl03$txtValue>
```

This is much different than the simple example... I am not sure how to code this input in my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
ieDoc.ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_txt.Value = "Hello"
```

and if that does not work:

```
ieDoc.getElementById("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_txt").Value = "Hello"
```

disclaimer: I have not tested the code

hint: what you are "playing" with is called "web-scraping". You can find decent examples [here](http://automatetheweb.net/)

Comment: Ok... the second one worked when I changed it slightly... you had: "ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_txt").Value but it needed to be: "ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue").Value

Comment: With ieDoc''''''''''''''''''''

Comment: .getElementByI ("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue").Value = "10378851"

Comment: .getElementById("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl00").Submit

Comment: End With'''''''''''''''''''